# PHPExcel can't read calculated value from different spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to parse several Excel documents.

One of them, called `SomeSheet1`, is a merge of all of them and its cell values are something like:

```
=IF(B11="","",VLOOKUP(B11,'SomeSheet2'!$C$10:$AE$1002,7,0))
```

I read that I can use `getFormattedValue()`, but it gives me an uncaught exception. I suppose it is because it cannot reference another spreadsheet.

Is there a way to get the value of these cells?

`Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'SomeSheet1 !BE11 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/timetable/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:291 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/timetable/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php(189): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/timetable/excelparser/ClassExcelParser.php(63): PHPExcel_Cell->getFormattedValue() #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/timetable/test/test.php(45): ClassExcelParser->parse() #3 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/timetable/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 291`

Comment: Do you mean from another Excel file, or from another worksheet in the same file? From the syntax of that formula, it's from another worksheet! What is the exception that you get? Because it should allow references to another worksheet

Comment: @MarkBaker, another worksheet

Comment: @MarkBaker, I posted exception

Comment: The exception suggests that the problem is with the content of cell B11: what's the formula in B11?

Comment: @MarkBaker, =VLOOKUP([@[ Пәннің аталуы / Наименование дисциплины]],'Свод дисц'!$D$9:$AS$2000,42,0). I found that it gives me error only in this cell, others work fine.